# Is there any way to optimize following program where I am trying to rotate array by given input argument

Tags: functional-programming

Do you think following code can be optimized more?

I am using two for loops, which I think it can be reduced to something better. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> rotateArray(ArrayList<Integer> A, int B) {
  ArrayList<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  B = B % A.size();
  boolean flag = false;
  for (int i = B; i < A.size(); i++) {         
      ret.add(A.get(i));                     
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < B; i++) {
      ret.add(A.get(i));        
  }     
  return ret;
 }
}
```

Comment: Ask code review related questions on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: What is your intention of doing so......

Comment: What language is this, Java? Please tag your question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are rather asking for an algorithm, of course there are better ways to achieve it. Think on the lines of :

You are given a function that takes input three parameters :
an array, 
a start index
and an end index

and then returns the same array after reversing the elements between these start and end indices.

Something like :

func([1,2,3,4,5],2,4) ==> 1,2,5,4,3

how would you use this function to achieve the required output?

Comment: Ohk! will try on that